# tab issue in safari browser while typing username and password

Tags: input, safari, tabs, passwords

when user is typing tab after enter username in box then cursor move to the password box and get back to the username input box after typing one or two letter.
I have create one method name moveToPassword() and i am  facing problem that whenever i am typing single character in username it is calling onInputChange(). it is running well in other browser only getting problem with safari ... second input block (where ng-if="login.isIOS" ) is for safari

### login.html

```
   _self.onInputChange = function (inputValue) {
        toggleLogin(inputValue);
    };

    _self.moveToPassword = function ($event) {
        if ($event.keyCode === 9) {
            document.getElementById("password").focus(); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description Toggle Login button as per Input conditions.
     * @returns {}
     */
    function toggleLogin(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue || inputValue === '') {
            _self.loginInputs.userName = inputValue;
        }
        _self.dropdownStatus = false;

        if (_self.loginInputs.userName !== undefined &&
            _self.loginInputs.userName.length !== 0 &&
            _self.loginInputs.password.length !== 0 &&
            !(basAuthService.authentication.isAuth && !basAuthService.authentication.isConfigReady)) {
            _self.loginButtonStatus = false;
        } else {
            _self.loginButtonStatus = true;
        }

        //For disable domain dropdown as per user conditions
        if (_self.loginInputs.userName.indexOf('@') > 0 || _self.loginInputs.userName.indexOf('\\') > 0) {
            _self.loginInputs.domain = '';
            _self.dropdownStatus = true;
        }
    }`
```

`